# TypeScript Error Cannot find name on 'SyncClient' Twilio

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic2, twilio

I am creating an ionic app and everytime I try to use the library `twilio-chat` on my project via npm install I always got an error on `.d.ts` files

Import in my provider :

```
import { Client } from "twilio-chat";
```

Errors:
[image]

it seems the `.d.ts` files doesnt know where to look for the dependency modules they need. is it related on typings of typescript? I'm quite new to typescript.

but when I try to use the `cdn` it works perfectly fine.

I'm using

- `ionic: "3.18.0"`
- `typescript: "2.2.1"`
- `twlio-chat: "1.2.1"`

update: I were able to fix the SyncClient and Emc Client by mapping on were exactly `.d.ts` files. the only problem was there are twilio dependencies that doesn't have `.d.ts` files like `twilio-transport`, `twilsock` and `twilio-notifications`.

tsconfig.json contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "twilio-sync": ["node_modules/twilio-sync/lib"],
      "twilio-ems-client": ["node_modules/twilio-ems-client/lib"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "atom": {
    "rewriteTsconfig": false
  }
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

How do you compile typescript files? If you use tsconfig.json, make sure it uses "moduleResolution": "node" and node_modules can be found from upper directory. Maybe you want to look this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#node

Comment: Hi Anti by mapping `SyncClient` on my tsconfig I were able to fix it. My only problem now is that the other node_modules doesnt have `.d.ts` files do I need to make one for them? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Developer Evangelist here. Let me see if I can help you :) Technically this should work right out of the box since both the `twilio-sync` as well as the `twilio-chat` library are written in TypeScript. Could you post your `tsconfig.json` as well as the full list of dependencies you have installed so that we can take a look at it?

In general you'll have to install typings for any module that doesn't ship it's own typings.

Cheers,
Dominik